# Multiple unique columns but only unique combinations

Tags: mysql, unique-index

I've run into a problem with MySQL unique indicies. What I want to do is have something like this:

```
user_id  group_id
1        1
1        2
1        3
2        1
2        4
```

Where there can be multiple instances of the same user ID, as well as multiple instances of group IDs, but *only* allow unique combinations of the two. I'm using this with an `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` MySQL query, and I'm wondering what I need to do to the indexes on the table. Currently, I have this:

```
PRIMARY id
UNIQUE  user_id, group_id
```

But... a) is this enough and b) am I doing it right to get what I'm looking for?

Thanks for any help

James

Comment: There's no `id` field in your sample table? Otherwise the second `UNIQUE` key will do exactly what you want. Multiple user_ids, multiple group_ids, but allow only one of any particular userid+groupid in the table.

Comment: Yeah there is an ID column. I just left it out for brevity :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost got it. If you use MyISAM engine, you can do this:

```
CREATE TABLE your_table(
id int unsigned not null auto_increment,
group_id int unsigned,
primary key(group_id, id)
) ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

Try it and see the behavior, it'll increment the id the way you specified in your example and you'll have unique constraint too.

Comment: So simple! Thanks very much. I should have just tried trial and error instead of posting, but hey, it works! +1 and a correct answer for you.

Comment: Heh, thing is - the information about this is not really easily "googleable", and it's only MyISAM engine that supports it (InnoDB won't do it that way for example, you'll get sequential keys no matter how you specify the primary key). I'm glad I could help, cheers :)